# Which command saves data faster in R

Tags: r, data.table

Does anyone know which method of saving data is faster `fwrite` from `data.table` or `saveWorkbook` in `openxlsx`?

Comment: Run both of them: the one which finished first is faster.

Comment: The fastest is probably `save` and `saveRDS` - but you will only be able to open those files in R.

Comment: In my benchmarking, I thought [feather](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/) was pretty fast. Not sure how it compares to the above mentioned packages, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer, but too long for a comment.

The easy comment is: Just try to benchmark your code with `bench::mark`

```r
library(bench)
...

mark(
  data.table::fwrite(data, tempfile()),
  openxlsx::saveWorkbook(data, tempfile()),
  check = FALSE
)
```

The slightly longer comment is: Do you just want to have the fastest read/write? Then you might want to look into [`fst`](https://www.fstpackage.org/) and or [`qs`](https://github.com/traversc/qs).

I presented a lightning talk at our last R User Group where I benchmarked different read/write speeds, memory usages, file sizes etc. You find the slides [here](https://github.com/DavZim/io-benchmarks).

Hope that helps